# How to understand super when overriding method_missing?

Tags: ruby

```
class MyClass
  def method_missing(id,*args,&block)
    return A if something
    return B if something_else
    super
  end
end
```

Here if neither A nor B is returned, super is called, which will raise a NoMethodError. I suppose here the super is the superclass of MyClass. However, how is NoMethodError raised since here we are solely calling super without calling the missing method along with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your supposition is wrong. `super` is not the superclass of `MyClass`. It is a call of a method with the same name on the superclass of `MyClass`.

Comment: I see. So method_missing is called again on the superclass of MyClass, right?

Comment: To be more precise, `super` is a call to a method of the same name on the next ancestor of the current receiver which responds to that method.  This might be a method of the superclass, or it might be a mixin or singleton class in the ancestor chain.